# How to target previous version of iOS in XCode4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode4, release

How can I target a previous version of iOS in XCode4? My app is building only for iOS 4.3 devices and I'd like users with iOS 3.0 installed to be able to run the app as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the project in the Project Navigator and the then the target in the detail view.  Under the summary tab you have the Deployment Target.  Set it to 3.0.  Alternatively you can set the iOS Deployment Target in the build settings.  Both ways change the same parameter, it's just two different ways to access it.

This will allow your app to run on iOS 3.0 but it's still compiling against SDK 4.3 which is required by Xcode 4.  So be careful that you don't use any SDK items that require an OS newer than 3.0 or if you do that they're properly checked with an if statement.  These issues can be a bit of a pain since they manifest themselves at runtime.